# how can i extract feature by using VGG

Tags: feature-extraction, vgg-net

```
I want to extract features of my dataset by using VGG16 but when I research I find just how to classify images not how to extract their features.
```

can anyone help me by sharing an article that can help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the last layer, output = 4096 feature

```
model = VGG19(input_shape=(224,224,3))
model_new = Model(model.input, model.layers[-2].output)
```